# Pass null parameter to controller with ActionLink

Tags: razor, parameters, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, actionlink

I have a view that lists a bunch of categories:

```
<ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("All", "Index", "Products")</li>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ProductCategories)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Index", new { id = item.Id }, null)</li>
    }
</ul>
```

As shown I should get a list of category links, the top one being "All" and the following ones being the respective category name, with an id passed to the controller.

My controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    var categories = _productCategoryRepository.GetAll().OrderByDescending(f => f.Name);
    var items = id == null
        ? _productItemRepository.GetAll().OrderBy(f => f.Name).ToList()
        : _productCategoryRepository.GetSingle((int)id).ProductItems.OrderBy(f => f.Name).ToList();

    var model = new ProductsViewModel()
                    {
                        ProductCategories = categories,
                        ProductItems = items
                    };

    return View(model);
}
```

So the categories should always be the same. But the items should show every item, when the **id** is *null* and the items of the specific category when the **id** is set.

That all works absolutely great, so when I click a category link. I get to  the url like this:

**/Products/Index/3**

Great! Now I click the "All" link, but it's routing me to **/Products/Index/3** even though I clearly don't pass a parameter to it. I tried passing a null value:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Alle", "Index", "Products", new { id = null })
```

But I then get the error: *Cannot assign 'null' to anonymous type property.*

How can I force null to be passed to my index controller?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your controller action will be happy enough to accept a nullable `int`, so give it a nullable `int` like so!

```
@Html.ActionLink("Alle", "Index", "Products", new { id = (int?)null })
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! It did not come to my mind that I can cast it inside anonymous object and it will recognize the type that way.